# how to disable mutliple buttons when one is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick

I have two buttons currently and when either one is clicked i'd like both to be disabled.

currently im using:

```
<button type="button" class="disapprove-button" id="123abc" onclick="this.disabled=true;">
<img src="/downvote.png" alt="Downvote" /></button>
```

to disable the button when clicked, but this allows the other one to remain active.

the other one is nearly the exact same code but for a different function:

```
<button type="button" class="approve-button" id="123abc" onclick="this.disabled=true;">
<img src="/upvote.png" alt="Upvote" /></button>
```

I know theirs a way to do this with javascript/jquery but i'm not very familiar with those two.

Comment: Do you not know how to reference an element?

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you just want us to do your job (or hobby) for you?

Comment: $('#continueButton').attr("disabled", true);

Comment: @JohnK. -- `.prop("disabled", true)`

Comment: updated with a fiddle!!!have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used class targeting instead

```
var voteB =  $(".disapprove-button, .approve-button");

$(voteB).on('click', function() {
     $(voteB).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/imemine29/VFt9E/

Answer (score 0):

First of all,you cannot give same id to different elements,Id`s are unique.You can assign a common class,but not common id.

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BPZT7/3/)

just a sample.

```
$('#upvote_id').on('click', function() {
     $('#down_vote_id').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     $('#upvote_id').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Make diffirent ids for buttons.

```
var buttons =  $("#id_button1, #id_button_2");//find buttons in DOM

buttons.click(function(){
  buttons.prop("disabled", true);//disable both buttons onclick event
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A3W8T/

Answer for comment:
Yes, you can use any selectors:

```
var buttons =  $(".disapprove-button, .approve-button");//find buttons in DOM

buttons.click(function(){
  buttons.prop("disabled", true);//disable both buttons onclick event
})
```

Comment: im currently using the ids to pass information, any way around this?